# Transforming a JSON Object using Dataweave 2.0

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I am getting a JSON response from an API GET request into my Mule flow which looks somewhat like the below JSON. I am trying to map this to achieve an output list where each customer looks somewhat like below. problem is the company card number which sits under custom attributes and also I keep getting the error show at the bottom. I have tried to use the payload map (value,key) function which is giving me that error. When I use pluck I get all items listed under id, firstname etc but I want them individually soa repeated list.
Thank you!

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 17837,
            "group_id": 2,
            "email": "catherinebrugge@tprg.com",
            "firstname": "Catherine5",
            "lastname": "Brugge",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "customer_id",
                    "value": "29a8-303b-01c7fe28"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 17839,
            "group_id": 2,
            "email": "catherineb@123.com",
            "firstname": "Catherine",
            "lastname": "Brugge",
            "website_id": 2,
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "id": 33773,
                    "customer_id": 17839,
                    "region": {
                        "region_code": null,
                    },
                    "region_id": 0,
                    "street": [
                        "123 Kings Road"
                    ],
                    "default_billing": true
                }
            ],
            "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "company_card_number",
                    "value": "100000000"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "ustomer_id",
                    "value": "29a8-c3443e-014062"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 18357,
            "group_id": 2,
            "email": "catherinebrugge@543.com",
            "firstname": "Catherine",
            "lastname": "Brugge",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "company_card_number",
                    "value": "888243"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "customer_id",
                    "value": "2b02-88583c-021559"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "group_id",
                        "value": "2",
                        "condition_type": "equal"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 3
}
```

```
You called the function 'map' with these arguments: 

1: Object ({items: [{id: ...)
 2: Function ((value:Any, key:Any) -> ???)
```

```
{
    "customers":{
        "id": payload.items.id,
        "group_id": payload.items.group_id,
        "firstname":payload.firstname,
        "lastname": payload.lastname,
        "email": payload.email,
        "company_card_number": ???
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello Catherine, please let us know what is desired output here? so we can help you in transforming this

Comment: Please also  add the complete current DataWeave script and the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few guesses as to what you're looking for.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  skipNullOn="everywhere"

fun getCardNumber(customer) = customer.custom_attributes[?($.attribute_code == 'company_card_number')][0].value

---
customers:payload.items map ($ - "custom_attributes" ++ "company_card_number": getCardNumber($))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dale this works great! My next issue is that I want to filter the customers on the company_card_number but I always get an empty object even though the number is present.

I have tried this with and without quotes but nothing is returned... Thanks!

```%dw 2.0
```output application/json
```---
```payload filter (payload.customers.company_card_number == "100000000")

Comment: I have the same problem when I try to filter on any of the email addresses. It just returns [ ]

Comment: @CatherineBrugge Not quite sure what you're saying.  Can you post another question with input, expected output and your dataweave and I'll take a look at it?